# Bubble chart of Word/phrase frequency and it's %

Tags: python, matplotlib

Lets say I have a data like below

```
[('thank_you', 13443),
 ('best_regards', 9833),
 ('cloud_product', 9658),
 ('support_eng', 8147),
 ('your_x', 8106),
 ('expert_fx', 8103),
 ('accreditation_program', 8066),
 ('http_communitys, 7940)]
```

And I want to show the visualization of each word/phrase frequency by count and % in a bubble chart where the size of bubble would be the count freq or %freq

Any idea how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would start off by suggesting that you should star the [Awesome-Python LIST](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#data-visualization)

Now I would personally suggest this library [**HERE**](http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/)
It offers all sorts of charts, very intuitive and easy to use.

```
pie_chart = pygal.Pie()
pie_chart.title = 'Browser usage in February 2012 (in %)'
pie_chart.add('IE', 19.5)
pie_chart.add('Firefox', 36.6)
pie_chart.add('Chrome', 36.3)
pie_chart.add('Safari', 4.5)
pie_chart.add('Opera', 2.3)
pie_chart.render()
```

This is how simple it is to make a chart. (the second argument is **%** )

Comment: I didn't ask pie chart. I was asking bubble chart

Comment: Um, sorry I don't know what you mean by a bubble chart. You can either use this library or find another one in the list I've provided you with.